# Setting a style's TargetType property to a generic class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, targettype

Is it possible to set a style's TargetType property in XAML to a Generic Class?

```
public class Selector<T> : Control { }
```

and then in xaml

```
<Style x:TargetType="Selector">
<Setter Property="MyProperty" Value="Green" />
</Style>
```

This wont work because Selector is missing a type argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind to an open generic type like `List<T>`, you can however bind to a closed generic type like `List<Person>` by defining a placeholder type.

**C#**:

```
class People : List<Person> {}
```

**XAML**:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type People}"> ... </Style>
```

**Update**: You either need to specify [`TargetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx) *or* the `x:Key` property for a Style, not both.

Comment: I have stumbled onto this solution for similar xaml+generics situations. I already have 10 closed types per generic, I was hoping to not need to duplicate the style information.

Comment: yeah... afaik XAML doesn't directly grasp generics... yet.

Answer (score 1):

Generics have pretty limited support in XAML.  That being said, Mike Hillberg has a pretty interesting post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehillberg/archive/2006/10/06/LimitedGenericsSupportInXaml.aspx) about custom markup extensions that may help.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're using regular WPF, not Silverlight? If I'm not mistaken, you could say this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="{x:Type Control}">
</Style>
```

Comment: Yes its WPF, but I need to connect it to a generic class - I'll update the question to be more clear.